# Wordpress Insert line in DB when clicking a button

Tags: php, ajax, database, 500-internal-error

when clicking buttonHdp, I wold like to launch the php code in order to insert a line in DB.

Script

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
jQuery(function($){
        $("#ButtonHdp").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://.../wp-content/themes/generatepress/process.php',
                data: '',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#result").html(response);
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                  console.log(error);
                }
            });
        });
}); });
</script>
```

process.php

```
<?php
    
function ButtonPubVideoHdp_InsertData() {
    global $wpdb;
    $User_Name = 'New name';
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'table_test';
    $wpdb->insert( 
        $table_name, 
        array( 
            'User_Name' => $User_Name, 
        ) 
    );

}

?>
```

The console log displays `"Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined"`.
While the php code is performed directly in function.php, it works.
Please help

Comment: making direct AJAX requests to PHP files in a theme or plugin is a major mistake and has security maintenance and reliability issues. timthumb.php is a notorious example of it going wrong, but also none of the WP APIs will be present unless you manually load them. If you want to make an AJAX request you should make it to WordPress instead of standalone files and use the REST API or the legacy admin ajax API to handle it in your code.

Comment: Thank so much for your answer. The final target is to insert data in the db after clicking a button. If there is any other way than using ajax, it is welcome.

Comment: Using AJAX is fine, but not to a standalone PHP file inside your theme

Comment: Great, I go on this way.

Comment: Use the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) or [wp_ajax_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_action/)

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems here. Resolving one leads to another.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined

In your JavaScript code, you set the `success` key to a function

> ```js
> function (data) {
>     $("#result").html(response);
> }
> ```

- `response` is not defined. The callback has a function parameter of `data`, not `response`. This causes the error.
- `.html(…)` sets the HTML content of an element. `data` would not be a reasonable variable to use since it is not HTML.
- Returning something useful from the PHP code would provide no value without an element matching the query selector `#result`.

Therefore, **delete the line** `$("#result").html(response);`.

Then your function would still not be called. Making a request to `process.php` would declare the function but not call it. You need to actually call the function you declare, `ButtonPubVideoHdp_InsertData()`, in your PHP.

---

This is not the right way to make AJAX requests with WordPress. Please follow the guidance at:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Thank so much for your answer. I follow your advices.
The final target is to insert data in the db after clicking a button. 
If there is any other way than using ajax, it is welcome.